# Solving $|x^2-2x|+|x-4|>|x^2-3x+4|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> How do I solve $|x^2-2x|+|x-4|>|x^2-3x+4|?$

I can see the difference of the two terms on the left gives the term on the right. Now,what should I do? Is there any general method for solving $$|a|+|b|>|a-b|?$$

Thanks for any help!!

Comment: Hint: triangle inequality. When does equality occur?

Comment: The absolute value gives a norm for the real line.

Comment: @ZainPatel Its an interesting approach I understand but I didn't get it...

Comment: @tatan Let $a = x^2 - 2x$ and $b = x-4$. Then $|a - b| \leqslant |a| + |b|$ for all $a,b$. We want to seperate out the case where equality holds.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note that $|x^2-2x|+|x-4|=|x^2-2x|+|-x+4|\ge|x^2-3x+4|$ with the equality holds if and only if $x^2-2x$ and $-x+4$ are of the same sign.

Therefore, $|x^2-2x|+|x-4|>|x^2-3x+4|$ if and only if $x^2-2x$ and $x-4$ are of the same sign. So we have

\begin{align*}
(x^2-2x)(x-4)&>0\\
x(x-2)(x-4)&>0\\
0<x<2 \quad\textrm{or}\quad x&>4
\end{align*}

Comment: $x-4$ and $-x+4$ have the same magnitude but are of opposite signs. They are the same absolute value, just like $|-8|=8=|8|$

Comment: Can you explain why "$|x^2-2x|+|x-4|>|x^2-3x+4|$ if and only if $x^2-2x$ and $x-4$ are of the same sign"?

Comment: We have two possibilities: (1) $|x^2-2x|+|x-4|=|x^2-3x+4|$ and (2) $|x^2-2x|+|x-4|>|x^2-3x+4|$. (1) holds if and only if  $x^2-2x$ and $-x+4$ are of the same sign. So (2) holds if and only if $x^2-2x$ and $-x+4$ are of the opposite signs. This is equivalent to the case when $x^2-2x$ and $x-4$ are of the same sign

Comment: How do I make sure $|x^2-1|+|x^2-4|$ is never less than $3$?

Comment: $|x^2-1|+|x^2-4|=|x^2-1|+|4-x^2|\ge|x^2-1+4-x^2|=3$. Is it related to this problem?

Comment: Yeah..its related to this problem...

Answer (score 4):

rewring as
$$|x||x-2|+|x-4|>x^2-3x+4$$ since $$x^2-3x+4>0$$ for all real $x$
we distinguish four cases:
$$x\geq 4$$
$$2\le x<4$$
$$0\le x<2$$
$$x<0$$
$$x(x-2)+x-4>x^2-3x+4$$
$$x(x-2)-x+4>x^2-3x+4$$
$$x(-x+2)-x+4>x^2-3x+4$$
$$-x(-x+2)-x+4>x^2-3x+4$$
Can you finish?
Finally we find: $$0<x<2$$ or $$x>4$$

Comment: Why the downvote(-1)?

Comment: why the $-1$ ? what is wrong?

Comment: Yeah...people downvote randomly I think...;-(

Comment: Can I flag it for moderator attention?

Comment: This solution is systematic and clear.

Comment: Although we have a seemingly easier solution with the use of triangle inequality. This method has the point. Triangle inequality does not work for the inequality$|x^2-2x|+|x-4|>|x^2-3x+3|$. But this method works perfectly.

Comment: I flagged it for reversal of downvote but it was declined...

Answer (score 3):

Solving this is just a matter of using the **definition** of |x|.

This is |x||x- 2|+ |x+ 4|> |x^2- 3x+ 4|.

x^2- 3x+ 4 is positive for all x so we need to consider three cases:

x< -4.  Then all of x, x- 2, and x+ 4 are negative.  This is (-x)(2- x)- (x+ 4)= x^2- 3x- 4> x^2- 3x+ 4. That reduces to -4> 4 which is never true. There is no x< -4 that satisfies this.

-4< x< 0.  x+ 4 is positive but x and x+ 2 are still negative so this is (-x)(2- x)+ (x+ 4)= x^2- x+ 4> x^2- 3x+ 4.  That reduces to 2x> 0 but this case is for x< 0 so there is no x between -4 and 0 that satisfies this.

0< x< 2.  Now both x+ 4 and x are positive while x- 2 is negative so this is (x)(2- x)+ (x+ 4)= -x^2+ 3x+ 4> x^2- 3x+ 4.  That reduces to -2x^2+ 6x= x(6- 2x)> 0.  A product is positive if both numbers are positive or if both numbers are negative.  Either x> 0 and 6> 2x so x> 3 or x< 0 and 6< 2x.  The first is satisfied for x> 3 and the second for x< 0.  Neither of those is true for 0< x< 2 so there is no x that satisfies this.

2< x.  Now all three terms are positive so this is (x)(x- 2)+ x+ 4= x^2- x+ 4> x^2- 3x+ 4.  That reduces to 2x> 0 or x> 0. Since, here, x> 2 x is also greater than 0. This inequality is satisfied for x> 2..